# Multiple if statements in list comprehension with one iterator

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was studying list comprehension and came across the possibility of adding several conditions. I do not know what behavior I expected, but I cannot explain what I am getting. Why does 1 turn into 3, 2 remains a 2, and 3 turns into 6?

```
a = [x if x % 2 == 0 else x * 2 if x % 3 == 0 else x * 3 for x in range(1, 11)]
```

output:

```
[3, 2, 6, 4, 15, 6, 21, 8, 18, 10]
```

Comment: You should at least *try* to explain the code that *you wrote*.

Comment: Note that this is not so much the "standard" condition used in list comprehension (which filters the input, so the output tends to contain fewer elements), but a nested ternary condition. This example can be used outside of a list comprehension as well.

Comment: This also falls in the category: don't do this, unless you're attempting to enter an obfuscated Python contest (for which it makes a poor entry, but still).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-writing as a loop and converting the [conditional expressions](https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/#conditional-expressions-pythons-ternary-operator) to full `if`/`elif`/`else` statements might help explain it:

```
a = []
for x in range(1, 11):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        temp = x
    elif x % 3 == 0:
        temp = x * 2
    else:
        temp = x * 3
    a.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

For 1 it goes like this:

`1 % 2 = 1`, so it goes to `else` clause,

`1 % 3 = 1`, so it also goes to `else` clause

and it gets into `x*3` which is `1*3 = 3`

When you write `x if condition else y`, you get `x` only if condition is true. So since the condition is false, you go to the `else` clause. You can look at it like this:

```
x if x % 2 == 0 else (x * 2 if x % 3 == 0 else x * 3) for x in range(1, 11)
```